# Deleting particular string value from column from table

Tags: mysql

If my column contains these values

```
"Added by Manu on 31-12-2013 & 12thFeb2014"
"Added by Manu on 01-01-2014 [nx-RP-S]"
"Added by Manu on 8thApril2014 (Pnxs)"
added by Manu on 7thFeb2014 [np1PUNCTnp2]
```

then I want a query which delete only this string

```
"Added by Manu on 31-12-2013 & 12thFeb2014"`
"Added by Manu on 01-01-2014 ""
"Added by Manu on 8thApril2014"
"added by Manu on 7thFeb2014 " rest [nx-RP-S],(Pnxs),[np1PUNCTnp2]
```

respectively will as it is in column.

Example if original value is `"Added by Manu on 01-01-2014 [nx-RP-S]"` then I want to delete only `"Added by Manu on 01-01-2014"` from column, and if original value is `"Added by Manu on 31-12-2013 & 01-01-2014"` then make it `null`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will remove the part from [

```
 select SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column, '[', 1) as removedPart from table1
```

EDIT: for you corrected requirement try this:

```
 select CASE WHEN your_column NOT Like '%[%' then 'NULL'

 else SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column, ' ', -1)  end as modified from table1
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4c1b/9)

EDIT2:

for the update statment use this:

```
  Update table1 
  set your_column = 
  CASE WHEN your_column NOT Like '%[%' then 'NULL'
  else SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column, ' ', -1)  end
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ceb7/1)

Comment: Sorry I corrected my requirement i want to delete "Added by Manu on 01-01-2014" .

Comment: @ echo_Me Thank you .but In case of "Added by Manu on 01-01-2014" also it should make null,Only in case of "Added by Manu on 01-01-2014 [nx-RP-S]" modified will be "[nx-RP-S]"

Comment: how to write update query for same.. so that coloum get updated

Comment: edited my answer for the update statment .look edited2 .